# Returning highest costing item in a decorated item? Removing that Item?

Tags: c++, decorator

Say, for example, I had:

```
class Beverage
{
private:
    string description;
    double cost;
public:
    virtual string getDescription() { return description; }
    virtual double cost() { return cost };
    virtual Beverage* returnHighestCostingItem()
    {
        //
    }
    virtual void removeHighestCostingItem()
    {
        //
    }
};

class Espresso : public Beverage
{
public:
    string getDescription()
    {
            return "Espresso";
    }
    double cost()
    {
        return 1.99;
    }
};

class Latte : public Beverage
{
public:
    string getDescription()
    {
            return "Latte";
    }
    double cost()
    {
        return 1.79;
    }
};

class condimentDecorator : public Beverage
{
public:
    virtual string getDescription() = 0;
    virtual Beverage* returnHighestCostingItem()
    {
        //
    }
    virtual void removeHighestCostingItem()
    {
        //
    }
};

class Whip : public condimentDecorator
{
private:
    Beverage* beverage;
public:
    Whip(Beverage* beverage)
    {
        this->beverage = beverage;
    }
    double cost()
    {
        return beverage->cost() + 0.20;
    }
};

class Milk : public condimentDecorator
{
private:
    Beverage* beverage;
public:
    Milk(Beverage* beverage)
    {
        this->beverage = beverage;
    }
    string getDescription()
    {
        return beverage->getDescription() + ", Milk";

    }
    double cost()
    {
            return beverage->cost() + 0.10;
    }
};

class Soy : public condimentDecorator
{
private:
    Beverage* beverage;
public:
    Soy(Beverage* beverage)
    {
        this->beverage = beverage;
    }
    string getDescription()
    {
        return beverage->getDescription() + ", Soy";

    }
    double cost()
    {
            return beverage->cost() + 0.15;
    }
};
```

And I were to do:

```
Beverage* coffee = new Espresso();
coffee = new Whip(coffee);
coffee = new Milk(coffee);
coffee = new Soy(coffee);

Beverage* coffee2 = new Latte();
coffee2 = new Whip(coffee2);
coffee2 = new Soy(coffee2);
```

I'm trying to return a pointer to the highest costing item, be it a beverage or condiment, without knowing how it is made up. For example given `coffee2`, how could I return a pointer to `Latte`?

Also how could I remove this item and keep the rest of the object intact. For example given `coffee`, how could I remove `Latte`, then if called again it would remove `Whip`? And can be called until only one item remaining?

NOTE: Without using any standard libraries

Comment: A pointer can point to only one address...

Comment: So what I'm trying to do is impossible?

Comment: My opinion is that you are over-using inheritance

Comment: The code came straight out of the Head First Design Patterns book. Is it not recommended or outdated?

Comment: I suppose it's fine in order to teach what the decorator pattern is. But if you were actually implementing a system for prices of drinks and condiments, using inheritance like this would be over-kill, and makes simple operations (like the ones you are asking about) much more difficult.

Comment: Yea, I see what you're saying. Thanks!